# Setting global sass variables in a vue project

Tags: vue.js, sass, configuration

I created a vue.config.js file to set some global sass variables (just like the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders) specifies), however when trying to access the variables in a component, I get an undefined error. Adding the same import statement manually in the component works, but somehow it's not being picked up from inside the vue.config.js file. I checked that I have node-sass and sass-loader installed and that the vue.config.js is in the project root (next to the package.json). What am I missing?

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                data: `
                    @import "@/assets/styles/_variables.scss";
                `
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 6):

Change `data` to `prependData`

```js
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                prependData: `
                    @import "@/assets/styles/_variables.scss";
                `
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about this here: [pre-loader docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules)

Comment: If you are using **.scss** files use `scss` loaderOption instead of `sass`. Otherwise you may get an `SassError: semicolons aren't allowed in the indented syntax`

Answer (score 6):

this code is for vue3

install:

## Sass

```
npm install -D sass-loader@^10 sass
```

## fibers

```
npm install -D fibers
```

## Style Resources Loader

```
npm i style-resources-loader -D
```

in your vue.config.js (root level project)

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                additionalData: `
                    @import "@/assets/styles/scss/_variables.scss";
                `
            }
        }
    }
}enter image description here
```

symbol `@` means that your file start from src folder

Answer (score 3):

1. `npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader`
2. Create file 'vue.config.js' in the root
3. Add code below. *Remember - @ refers to /src folder*

   ```
   module.exports = {
     css: {
       loaderOptions: {
         sass: {
           data: '@import "@/assets/css/variables/_colors.scss";'
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. Restart the project

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to troubleshoot without the full context, so here are several options you can try:

1. Ensure you've restarted the dev environment since changing the config (re-run `yarn dev` or `npm run dev`)
2. Keep the template literal to one line, as is used in docs. This shouldn't make a difference, but it might. (e.g. `` data: `@import "@/assets/styles/_variables.scss";` ``)
3. As you probably know, the underscore in front of a sass file denotes a sass partial. A partial is not used in the example, so it is possible that this has an effect as well. (e.g. rename `_variables.scss` to `variables.scss` and use `` data: `@import "@/assets/styles/variables.scss";` ``)
4. Ensure that the `sass-loader`, `node-sass`, and `css-loader` packages are up to date.
5. Try using the path without the slash after the `@`. e.g. `@assets/styles/_variables.scss`.
6. Try with a `~` instead of the `@`. e.g. `~assets/styles/_variables.scss`. If nothing else has worked, try replacing the `@` with `src` as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Point of clarification: when you say ensure everything is up-to-date, do you mean the latest version or simply the one specified in package.json? I tried everything else and it sadly didn't fix things.

Comment: @Phendan No problem! And I mean the latest version, or at least the minimum version compatible with the documented API. The global variable API wasn't always available. So unless it's a fresh project, upgrading the packages would be worth your while.