# Vue Stylus Sass Variables

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, stylus

After integrating stylus into my Vue3 application, my global css variables no longer work (loaded through `prependData` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59610004)).

Old, working code (no stylus):

```
<style>
  .item {
    background-color: $bgColor;
  }
</style>
```

New code, doesn't work (w/ stylus):

```
<style lang="stylus">
.item 
  background-color: $bgColor;
</style>
```

---

Is it possible to update my old code to leverage stylus and keep my variable structure? Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: The answer you linked applies to Vue2. Apparently, there's [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68140865/1891677) for Vue3. Which one have you followed? Are there any visible compile errors?

Comment: Thanks @tao. The "old code" above works fine and there are no compile errors. However, after switching to stylus, the variable doesn't get passed into the css (in the inspector it reads `background-color: $bgColor;`

Comment: What file you are importing through `prependData`? `.scss` will not work with stylus

Comment: I see, thanks so much @Duannx. What if I used css custom properties in `prependData` instead of scss? The goal is to have global style variables in a central file.

Comment: If you use CSS custom properties you don't even need to import it through `prependData` Just add it to your main CSS file and it will work